# Javascript Input Checker

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input, alert

I have a name input checker using Javascript and I'm struggling to see the issue. When the input has been entered and matches the array, the site should return ("Welcome" . inputValue) as an alert. However, I am getting an alert but it only says "undefined". If the person types in the incorrect name (doesn't match the array) it does feedback "User not know" As it is meant to. So the only issue is when the input value matches the array it gives the result "undefined".

```js
var x = ["Bob", "James", "Alan", "Emilie", "Donna", "Ashleigh", "Arthur", "John"];


function checkInput() {

  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputString").value;

  var test = x.indexOf(inputValue);

  if (test >= 0)
    alert("Welcome ".inputValue);

  else
    alert("User not known");

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="inputString">

  <button onclick="checkInput()">Evaluate input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not PHP; the string-concatenation is the `+` operator, not the period (`.`).

Answer (score 1):

The message format on `alert` function when matched is invalid.

It is needed to `"Welcome " + inputValue` instead of `"Welcome ".inputValue`.
On javascript, to join string, `+` operator is used.

```js
var x = ["Bob", "James", "Alan", "Emilie", "Donna", "Ashleigh", "Arthur", "John"];

function checkInput(event) {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
  var test = x.indexOf(inputValue);
  if (test >= 0)
    alert("Welcome " + inputValue);
  else
    alert("User not known");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="inputString">

  <button onclick="checkInput(event)">Evaluate input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just for the record, `"Welcome ".inputValue` is syntactically valid: it's reading the property `inputValue` on the string object `"Welcome "`, which _is_ undefined (hence no error is being thrown, but `undefined` is alerted).